# updating class variables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class-variables

I have a class variable named @@customers which I would like to continually update via a method.

I initialize the variable (as an empty array) at the top of my model. And then update it when the method update_customers is called:

```
class Customer
   @@customers = []

   def update_customers(new_customer)
      @@customers << new_customer
   end
end
```

I am concerned about @@customers being re-initialized to [] and losing the data. Could such re-initialization occur? When would it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope; `@@customers` will not be re-initialized to `[]` when `update_customers` is called from a new `Customer` object. That is how class variables work.

See http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/113-class-variables for an in-depth treatment of class variables.

As mentioned there:

> There aren't very many cases that you would need to use class variables.`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Customer
   @@customers = []

   def self.update_customers(new_customer)
      @@customers << new_customer
   end
end
```

Class variables are static. They are initialized just once.
It would be good if you declared update_customers as class method
You could call the method like

```
cust1 = Customer.new
Customer.update_customers cust1
```